# Spring security: authentication with http basic and form login

Tags: spring, web-services, authentication, spring-security

I have a huge and odd problem with authentication. I have two type of authentication, one through web page and it works and one for my web services it doesn't work. Indeed even if I don't give credentials the server accepts my authentication and goes ahead. It's a huge problem and I don't understand why, I would like to:

1) External webservices are /client/* URL and these must be authenticated. POST /client/file must not have authentication. All other web services don't serve so may be inaccessible or with authentication. This is a one shot authentication because check if user is enabled and give it web service result

2) Internal web service seems to work, all need authentication
What is wrong in my configuration?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration;

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration implements
    AuthenticationProvider {

        @Autowired
        private UserServices userServices;
        @Autowired
        LdapServices ldapServices;

        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
            String name = authentication.getName();
            String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            boolean isFind = ldapServices.ldapSearch(name, password);                           
            if (isFind){
                com.domain.User user = userServices.getByUsersEnabled(name);
                if (user!=null)
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+user.getRole().getRole()));          
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, authorities);
            }           
            else return null;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
            return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationConfiguration);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
        .csrf().disable()
        .antMatcher("/client/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        //Exclude send file from authentication because it doesn't work with spring authentication
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/client/file").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();      
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FormWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Autowired
        RoleServices roleServices;

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
            //Spring Security ignores request to static resources such as CSS or JS files.
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/static/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {         
            List<Role> roles=roleServices.getRoles();
            //Retrieve array of roles(only string field without id)
            String[] rolesArray = new String[roles.size()];
            int i=0;
            for (Role role:roles){
                rolesArray[i++] = role.getRole();
            }

            http
            .authorizeRequests() //Authorize Request Configuration
            .anyRequest().hasAnyRole(rolesArray)//.authenticated()
            .and() //Login Form configuration for all others
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            //important because otherwise it goes in a loop because login page require authentication and authentication require login page
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            //redirect on page 403 if user doens't exist in DART database
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .permitAll();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the new code, it seems to work:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    RoleServices roleServices;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        List<Role> roles = roleServices.getRoles();
        //Retrieve array of roles(only string field without id)
        String[] rolesArray = new String[roles.size()];
        int i=0;
        for (Role role:roles){
            rolesArray[i++] = role.getRole();
        }

        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .antMatcher("/client/**")
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        //Exclude send file from authentication because it doesn't work with spring authentication
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/client/file").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().hasAnyRole(rolesArray)
        .and()
        .httpBasic();   
    }
}
```

with `.antMatcher("/client/**")` catch all `/client` url request and use httpBasic authentication,  `.anyRequest().hasAnyRole(rolesArray)` allows authentication only for users with role.
`.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)` guarantees no session used by Spring Security. Cookies are not used and so each and every request needs to be re-authenticated. This stateless architecture plays well with REST APIs and their Statelessness constraint.